Why have my answers received downvotes?
I've gotten a lot of silly downvotes. My research into the answers is proven and the conclusions I give are logical.  
Does writing something on computer help memorize it?
For this question no one in their right mind would think that the fine motor skills used by handwriting mystically impart a greater understanding of the source material. I found two papers which prove as much. One gave a small advantage to handwriting and the other gave an equally small penalty for handwriting. 
Yet I have a -3 and counting?
https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/5389/what-are-the-brains-limits-of-human-trauma/5390#5390 
This question likewise has a -3 when it is also well researched and explains a stress based theory of mental illness. Likewise no honest scientist would stretch the  diathesis-stress model to the extreme to say that resilient individuals could survive many catastrophes and still be left unmarked. Many examples of resilient people though not psychopathic are psychologically scarred and traumatized.
Does the effect of naturalistic exposure on second language acquisition vary with age?
Its rather basic really. Neurological factors influenced by many things including age play an important role in the acquisition of language. No one thinks a demented 90 year old is going to learn a new language through immersion. 

This might be relevant: When is it appropriate to downvote an answer?


I've gotten a lot of silly downvotes. My research into the answers is
  proven and the conclusions I give are logical.

What I've noticed often when you receive feedback on answers, is you seem to mostly neglect the feedback. Read and understand where people are coming from when they give feedback. When they leave behind a comment it is usually to address problems with the post. You might personally feel and know your "research into the answers is proven and the conclusions I give are logical", but it is up to you to communicate that. If somebody raises issues with your premises or conclusions, it is up to you to either improve your argument in the post, refute their argumentations in the comments, or ask them to elaborate.

For this question no one in their right mind would think that the fine
  motor skills used by handwriting mystically impart a greater
  understanding of the source material.

Building up arguments by acting presumptuous e.g. "no one in their right mind" and "no honest scientist", "Its rather basic really." won't get you any further either. This is a scientific Q&A site, try to construct scientific argumentations. Instead of spending time on comments which add nothing to defending your point of view, try explaining/elaborating your point of view, or try understanding what might be incorrect about it.
One of the great aspects of Stack Exchange is not only can you help out people, but you can actually also learn new stuff. Be open to that!
